# can't get index to work with html razor

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am having some major problems with indexing my html on a partial view.
This is the model I'm using:

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(MyResources), Name = "EditTravelViewModel_TimeOfDeparture")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} måste fyllas i")]
public string TimeOfDeparture { get; set; }

[Display(ResourceType = typeof(MyResources), Name = "EditTravelViewModel_DateOfDeparture")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} måste fyllas i")]
public string DateOfDeparture { get; set; }
```

And this is the code for my partial:

```
<li class="clearfix">
  @*Use http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/*@
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfDeparture,
                   new {
                     @placeholder = MyResources.Shared_TravelPartial_TravelDate,
                     @class = "startdate datepicker", @readonly = "readonly",
                     @Style ="width: 90px;"
                   });
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TimeOfDeparture,
                     new { @placeholder = MyResources.Shared_TravelPartial_TravelTime,
                     @class ="startdate",
                     @Style = "width: 50px; margin-left: 15px;"
                   })
</li>
```

I am creating a travel and the first time when I go through this partial
the renderd html looks like this:

```
<input style="width: 90px;"
       class="startdate datepicker hasDatepicker valid"
       data-val="true"
       data-val-required="Datum f&amp;#246;r avresa m&amp;#229;ste fyllas i"
       id="ListEditTravelModel_0__DateOfDeparture"
       name="ListEditTravelModel[0].DateOfDeparture"
       placeholder="Avresedatum"
       readonly="readonly"
       type="text"
       value="2014-03-24">
<input style="width: 50px; margin-left: 15px;"
       class="startdate valid"
       data-val="true"
       data-val-required="Tid f&amp;#246;r avresa m&amp;#229;ste fyllas i"
       id="ListEditTravelModel_0__TimeOfDeparture"
       name="ListEditTravelModel[0].TimeOfDeparture"
       placeholder="Avr.tid"
       type="text"
       value="08:00">
```

Where you can se that it got `ListEditTravelModel_0__` before id and
name. But the second time it goes through the view with the same model
and all it renders this:

```
 <input style="width: 90px;"
        class="startdate datepicker hasDatepicker valid"
        id="ListEditTravelModel_1__DateOfDeparture"
        name="ListEditTravelModel[1].DateOfDeparture"
        placeholder="Avresedatum"
        readonly="readonly"
        type="text"
        value="2014-03-26">
 <input style="width: 50px; margin-left: 15px;"
        class="startdate valid"
        id="TimeOfDeparture"
        name="TimeOfDeparture"
        placeholder="Avr.tid"
        type="text"
        value="12:32">
```

Now the first input got the correct id and name but the second input
didn't get `ListEditTravelModel_1__` before the `id` and the name. Why
is this happening?